# MVC frameworks for .NET desktop applications

Tags: winforms, model-view-controller

I've been playing a lot with MVC lately in the forms of ASP.NET MVC and Django (MTV actually) and I must say that I love it.

Are there any similar frameworks for creating desktop WinForm apps?

Comment: Here's the landing page for MVC-in-WPF (AKA MVVM) I always pass around: http://blogs.sqlxml.org/bryantlikes/archive/2006/09/27/WPF-Patterns.aspx

Comment: Link moved: http://bryantlikes.com/archive/2006/09/27/WPF-Patterns.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of.

Most of my Winforms apps use the MVC or MVP pattern though. I've noticed that when creating Winforms apps you don't really need much of a framework. There is no routing infrastructure and no view-rendering. I find that I don't have to do much plumbing to use these patterns.

That might explain why there are no high profile frameworks in that space.

Answer (score 1):

A winforms app blends the view and controller into pretty much one thing, the form.  In other words, you are working with a model view/controller pattern.  Much of the work for the view and controller is already done.